# Autofill is failing after creating a "local" alias in my ~/.bashrc file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias, autofill

I added aliases to my .bashrc file. After I did that and ran source ~/.bashrc, auto fill started to throw errors in my Ubuntu command prompt. The error directs me to line 295 of my bash_completion file to look for incorrect syntax.

When I open this file and go to line 295, I see no incorrect syntax. Here are the lines of code I'm adding and the errors I'm receiving.

Alias I originally added to my `.bashrc` file:

`alias local='cd /mnt/c/Users/NYCZE/OneDrive/'`

Error thrown when I run `source ~/.bashrc` to implement this alias:

```
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 295: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 295: `('
```

Function which contains line 295 in my `bash_completion` file:

```
__reassemble_comp_words_by_ref()
{
    local exclude i j line ref  # This line right here is the problem one
    # Exclude word separator characters?
    if [[ $1 ]]; then
        # Yes, exclude word separator characters;
        # Exclude only those characters, which were really included
        exclude="${1//[^$COMP_WORDBREAKS]}"
    fi

    # Default to cword unchanged
    printf -v "$3" %s "$COMP_CWORD"
    # Are characters excluded which were former included?
    if [[ $exclude ]]; then
        # Yes, list of word completion separators has shrunk;
        line=$COMP_LINE
        # Re-assemble words to complete
        for (( i=0, j=0; i < ${#COMP_WORDS[@]}; i++, j++)); do
            # Is current word not word 0 (the command itself) and is word not
            # empty and is word made up of just word separator characters to
            # be excluded and is current word not preceded by whitespace in
            # original line?
            while [[ $i -gt 0 && ${COMP_WORDS[$i]} == +([$exclude]) ]]; do
                # Is word separator not preceded by whitespace in original line
                # and are we not going to append to word 0 (the command
                # itself), then append to current word.
                [[ $line != [[:blank:]]* ]] && (( j >= 2 )) && ((j--))
# Append word separator to current or new word
                ref="$2[$j]"
                printf -v "$ref" %s "${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}"
                # Indicate new cword
                [[ $i == $COMP_CWORD ]] && printf -v "$3" %s "$j"
                # Remove optional whitespace + word separator from line copy
                line=${line#*"${COMP_WORDS[$i]}"}
                # Start new word if word separator in original line is
                # followed by whitespace.
                [[ $line == [[:blank:]]* ]] && ((j++))
                # Indicate next word if available, else end *both* while and
                # for loop
                (( $i < ${#COMP_WORDS[@]} - 1)) && ((i++)) || break 2
            done
            # Append word to current word
            ref="$2[$j]"
            printf -v "$ref" %s "${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}"
                # Indicate new cword
                [[ $i == $COMP_CWORD ]] && printf -v "$3" %s "$j"
                # Remove optional whitespace + word separator from line copy
                line=${line#*"${COMP_WORDS[$i]}"}
                # Start new word if word separator in original line is
                # followed by whitespace.
                [[ $line == [[:blank:]]* ]] && ((j++))
                # Indicate next word if available, else end *both* while and
                # for loop
                (( $i < ${#COMP_WORDS[@]} - 1)) && ((i++)) || break 2
            done
            # Append word to current word
            ref="$2[$j]"
            printf -v "$ref" %s "${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}"
            # Remove optional whitespace + word from line copy
            line=${line#*"${COMP_WORDS[i]}"}
            # Indicate new cword
            [[ $i == $COMP_CWORD ]] && printf -v "$3" %s "$j"
        done
        [[ $i == $COMP_CWORD ]] && printf -v "$3" %s "$j"
    else
        # No, list of word completions separators hasn't changed;
        for i in ${!COMP_WORDS[@]}; do
            printf -v "$2[i]" %s "${COMP_WORDS[i]}"
        done
    fi
}
```

Comment: Well, which line is 295?

Comment: Don't override `local`. It's meaningful to the shell; pick a different name for your alias.

Answer (score 1):

`local` is a reserved keyword which is used extensively in many Bash completion packages, and generally in Bash code with functions. You really don't want to override it because that will break those packages. Call your alias something else.

(Maybe also don't use an alias at all - shell functions are much more versatile - but that doesn't change the substance of your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

`local` is a shell builtin.  You can see this from

```
type local
```

After your alias it has become a `cd`.  The same `type` command will now give

```
local is aliased to `cd /mnt/c/Users/NYCZE/OneDrive/'
```

Now, line 295 in my /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion file is

```
local cword words=()
```

So, `local` is no longer behaving as expected by that file.  The line in your file similarly uses `local`.

Comment: That was exactly it - I changed the alias to `_local` and now it works fine. Thanks for the help!